# How to structure a Dask application that processes a fixed number of inputs from a queue?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

We have a requirement to implement the following. Given a Redis channel that will provide a known number of messages:

1. For each message consumed from the channel:

   - Get a JSON document from Redis
   - Parse the JSON document, extracting a list of result objects
2. Aggregate across all result objects to produce a single result

We would like to distribute both steps 1 and 2 across many workers, and avoid collecting all results into memory. We would also like to display progress bars for both steps.

However, we can't see a nice way to structure the application such that we can see progress and keep work moving through the system without blocking as inopportune times.

For example, in step 1 if we read from the Redis channel into a queue then we can pass the queue to Dask, in which case we start processing each message as it comes in without waiting for all messages. However, we can't see a way to show progress if we use a queue (presumably because a queue typically has an unknown size?)

If we collect from the Redis channel into a list and pass this to Dask then we can see progress, but we have to wait for all messages from Redis before we can start processing the first one.

Is there a recommended way to approach this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Redis channels are concurrent-access-safe then you might submit many futures to pull an element from the channel.  These would run on different machines.

```
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
client = Client(...)

futures = [client.submit(pull_from_redis_channel, ..., pure=False) for _ in range(n_items)]
futures2 = client.map(process, futures)

progress(futures2)
```

Comment: Very nice! I was using Redis pub/sub which wouldn't work for this, but LPUSH + BLPOP acts like a point-point queue, and works very nicely with the above approach, thanks